# redirectMatch adding a mysterious query string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've upgraded someone's forum, and there are zillions of URLs that need 301 redirecting to their new homes. For example:

```
http://www.elfquest.com/social/forum/thread/7851/posters-in-comics/post_572519/
```

should point to

```
http://www.elfquest.com/forums/discussion/7851/posters-in-comics/post_572519/
```

I've figured out a redirectMatch that does the job:

```
redirectMatch 301 ^/social/forum/thread/(.*) http://www.elfquest.com/forums/discussion/$1
```

But it adds a curious query string to the end, like so:

```
http://www.elfquest.com/forums/discussion/7851/posters-in-comics/post_572519/?do=/forum/thread/7851/posters-in-comics/post_572519/
```

The result is handled without a problem by the new forum software (including the correct canonical reference in the HTML for search engines), but I'd really like to get it "right."

Here's my .htaccess

```
redirectMatch 301 ^/social/forum/thread/(.*) http://www.elfquest.com/forums/discussion/$1

RewriteOptions inherit
php_value include_path .:/home/elfquestftp/public_html/phpcode
Addhandler application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
#php_flag register_globals on

RewriteEngine on

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

That stuff at the bottom is the standard Wordpress .htaccess stuff. I've also tried this as a rewriterule before the wordpress block ...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^social/forum/thread/(.*)$ http://www.elfquest.com/forums/discussion/$1 [L,R=301]
```

...and it doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Don't mix `mod_rewrite` rules with `mod_alias` rules. Replace your `RedirectMatch` with this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^social/forum/thread/(.*) http://www.elfquest.com/forums/discussion/$1? [L,R=301,NC]
```

`?` at the end of target URL will strip off any existing query string.

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't do anything (the redirect doesn't happen at all, even when I remove everything in the .htaccess except the suggested lines)

Comment: Make sure this is very fist rule. What URL did you use in browser?

Comment: It is weird since you already have rewrite rules below and I presume those are working for you. Is this .htaccess in document root OR in some sub directory?